# A demonstration of the most basic form of a data breach or similar attack

Tags: attacks, cloud-computing, defense

I am currently working on my bachelor thesis regarding cloud security and found this neat article describing the "Notorious nine" written by the CSA:
[The notoruios nine](https://downloads.cloudsecurityalliance.org/initiatives/top_threats/The_Notorious_Nine_Cloud_Computing_Top_Threats_in_2013.pdf)

I am looking to try out some form of the most basic attack possible on a fairly insecure database that I my self am creating, both to have something do demonstrate, and to understand the issue better.

*So my question is, are there any articles or videos similar to a tutorial for this? Maybe encrypting and decrypting information, or just how to access a websites database* (In my case I just store user information, one site+db that stores encrypted, and one site+db that stores normal)

If you think this is too complicated for a beginner, then do you have any other suggestion of a small demonstration of attack/defense I could try that would be more beginner-friendly. Only requirement is that it effects a cloud-service in some way or form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's put buzzwords to the side for a moment shall we? Anything you need to connect with, on a networked level, is "clouded." A cloud is nothing more than a ***non-local*** networked business. These businesses house servers that **YOU** normally would. With that out the way, any attack you can do locally, would be similar. I don't believe you're going to find a publicly accessible network that'll allow you to "hack" per-se for the sake of your paper. You may find some CTF based sites, and distros, and or group based/game-like sites. With that out of the way, register an account on [EnigmaGroup](http://www.enigmagroup.org/pages/basics/) and try one of their SQL challenges or something